# how do to center the text input to be in center with two buttons that are also aligned centred

Tags: html, css

here is the html

```
<form id="ContactForm" action="">
  <div>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bg"><input class="input" type="text"></div>Name:
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bg"><input class="input" type="text"></div>Email:
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bg"><input class="input" type="text"></div>Phone:
     </div>
     <div class = "wrapper"> <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">Submit</a></div>
     <div class="wrapper"> <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()">Generate code</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

the css-

```
#ContactForm .button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:35px;
    width:90px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../images/button_form.gif) top repeat-x #308da2;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Comment: As of now your question title is badly framed. Can you try re-framing it?

Comment: fix your wording and accept answers on your questions...

Answer (score 2):

Apply

```
text-align: center
```

to your form's css.

Here http://jsfiddle.net/cpFZM/ is a rough example based on the code that you posted. This will centre-align everything. If you only want to centre-align certain elements then you simply need to apply the style to their containing `divs`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your css:

```
#ContactForm div {margin: 0px auto; width:130px}
```

Comment: how do you know the width is 130px?

Comment: He decides teh width, after he decides what width will the input type text will have ....

Comment: the widths for the buttons are different, so it won't center. Take a look at LeviBotelho's answer, it is the right one. If you are trying to center an inline or inline-block element with unknown or multiple widths, use `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no need of using so much `divs` to design a form. Use `label` tag instead.

**HTML**

```
 <form id="ContactForm" action="">
     <label>Name:<input class="input" type="text"></label>    
     <label>Email: <input class="input" type="text"></label>                         
     <label>Phone:<input class="input" type="text"></label>                     
     <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">Submit</a>
     <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()">Generate code</a>
</form>​
```

**CSS**

```
#ContactForm {width:90%; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    background:#e3f8f9; 
    border:#308da2 solid 1px; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding:10px 0}
label{display:block; margin:8px 0}
input{margin-left:15px}
#ContactForm .button {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../images/button_form.gif) top repeat-x #308da2;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 15px
}​
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AEv9Z/1/)**